# Spherical Hankel and Bessel in explicit form

Tags: special-functions

This is probably an easy question. When I type the spherical Hankel (first kind) and the Bessel function into Wolfram Alpha, it gives back an explicit form: the one you would get if you were to do it by hand from a series definition of these functions.

I would like the explicit form in *Mathematica* for the following expressions:

```
SphericalBesselJ[l, z]
SphericalHankelH1[l, z]
```

with `z = I*x`, where `I` is the imaginary unit.

Comment: An interesting note: in the Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation/SphericalBesselJ one finds an example `FunctionExpand[SphericalBesselJ[1, x]] `yielding `-(Cos[x]/x) + Sin[x]/x^2 `. When I do the same in Mma 10.0 Win. 7 I get this: `(Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] BesselJ[1/2 (1 + 2 l), z])/Sqrt[z] `. Strange, is it not?

Comment: @Alexei Boulbitch Thank you! Exactly what i was looking for, i have to make sre to use the help more often :D

Answer (score 5):

As noted by Alexei, all the built-in spherical Bessel functions are easily transformed to their trigonometric forms via `FunctionExpand[]`:

```
{{SphericalBesselJ[1, z], SphericalBesselY[1, z]},
 {SphericalHankelH1[1, z], SphericalHankelH2[1, z]}} // FunctionExpand
   {{-(Cos[z]/z) + Sin[z]/z^2, -(Cos[z]/z^2) - Sin[z]/z},
    {(E^(I z) (-I - z))/z^2, (E^(-I z) (I - z))/z^2}}
```

More generally, all the Bessel-type functions of half-integer order are either automatically converted to their elementary forms:

```
{{BesselJ[1/2, z], BesselY[1/2, z]}, {BesselI[1/2, z], BesselK[1/2, z]},
 {StruveH[1/2, z], StruveL[1/2, z]}}
   {{(Sqrt[2/π] Sin[z])/Sqrt[z], -((Sqrt[2/π] Cos[z])/Sqrt[z])},
    {(Sqrt[2/π] Sinh[z])/Sqrt[z], (E^-z Sqrt[π/2])/Sqrt[z]},
    {Sqrt[2/π]/Sqrt[z] - (Sqrt[2/π] Cos[z])/Sqrt[z],
     -(Sqrt[(2/π)]/Sqrt[z]) + (Sqrt[2/π] Cosh[z])/Sqrt[z]}}
```

or can be expanded into such with `FunctionExpand[]`:

```
{{HankelH1[1/2, z], HankelH2[1/2, z]}, {KelvinBer[1/2, z], KelvinBei[1/2, z]},
 {KelvinKer[1/2, z], KelvinKei[1/2, z]}} // FunctionExpand
   {{-((I E^(I z) Sqrt[2/π])/Sqrt[z]), (I E^(-I z) Sqrt[2/π])/Sqrt[z]},
    {(Sqrt[2/π] (-(1/2) Sqrt[2 - Sqrt[2]] Cosh[z/Sqrt[2]] Sin[z/Sqrt[2]] + 
     1/2 Sqrt[2 + Sqrt[2]] Cos[z/Sqrt[2]] Sinh[z/Sqrt[2]]))/Sqrt[z],
     (Sqrt[2/π] (1/2 Sqrt[2 + Sqrt[2]] Cosh[z/Sqrt[2]] Sin[z/Sqrt[2]] + 
     1/2 Sqrt[2 - Sqrt[2]] Cos[z/Sqrt[2]] Sinh[z/Sqrt[2]]))/Sqrt[z]},
    {(E^(-(z/Sqrt[2])) Sqrt[π/2] Sin[π/8 - z/Sqrt[2]])/Sqrt[z],
     -((E^(-(z/Sqrt[2])) Sqrt[π/2] Cos[π/8 - z/Sqrt[2]])/Sqrt[z])}}
```

---

Converting to the elementary form is not always recommended, especially if you are planning to do numerical evaluations with them. This is because the explicit forms are more often vulnerable to subtractive cancellation. Here is a particular illustration:

```
SphericalBesselJ[5, z] // FunctionExpand
   ((-945 + 105 z^2 - z^4) Cos[z])/z^5 + (15 (63 - 28 z^2 + z^4) Sin[z])/z^6

Plot[{SphericalBesselJ[5, z],
      ((-945 + 105 z^2 - z^4) Cos[z])/z^5 + (15 (63 - 28 z^2 + z^4) Sin[z])/z^6},
     {z, 0, 1/2}, PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[4], AbsoluteThickness[1]}]
```

[image: looks nasty near the origin]